# Apache & LDAP authentication

Tags: server, apache2, ldap, mediawiki

I am in the process of merging two LDAP directories to one server. To start with I've created a LDAP server with two forests, one for each of the old servers. This went well. Now I am trying to setup access to my mediawiki so that users from both forests can access it.

I know from AD that it is possible distinguish users with a domain and username either as 
domain\username or username@domain

Is this possible with LDAP? I've been trying different settings in my site-configuration without any luck.

I've enabled the following modules in apache:

- core_module (static)
- log_config_module (static)
- logio_module (static)
- mpm_prefork_module (static)
- http_module (static)
- so_module (static)
- alias_module (shared)
- auth_basic_module (shared)
- authn_alias_module (shared)
- authn_file_module (shared)
- authnz_ldap_module (shared)
- authz_default_module (shared)
- authz_groupfile_module (shared)
- authz_host_module (shared)
- authz_user_module (shared)
- autoindex_module (shared)
- cgi_module (shared)
- deflate_module (shared)
- dir_module (shared)
- env_module (shared)
- ldap_module (shared)
- mime_module (shared)
- negotiation_module (shared)
- php5_module (shared)
- reqtimeout_module (shared)
- rewrite_module (shared)
- setenvif_module (shared)
- ssl_module (shared)
- status_module (shared)

and my site configuration is:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap-grid>
        AuthLDAPBindDN cn=admin,dc=grid,dc=aau,dc=dk
        AuthLDAPBindPassword ***
        AuthLDAPURL ldap://harald:389/ou=People,dc=grid,dc=aau,dc=dk?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap-es>
        AuthLDAPBindDN cn=admin,dc=es,dc=aau,dc=dk
        AuthLDAPBindPassword ***
        AuthLDAPURL ldap://harald:389/ou=People,dc=es,dc=aau,dc=dk?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName aggersborg.grid.aau.dk
        ServerAdmin adm@grid.aau.dk

        DocumentRoot /opt/wiki
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                RedirectMatch ^/$ /wiki/
                Redirect /observium https://aggersborg.grid.aau.dk:8080
        </Directory>
        <Directory /opt/wiki/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All

                Order allow,deny
                allow from all

                AuthBasicProvider ldap-grid ldap-es
                AuthName "AAU HPC Wiki"
                AuthType Basic
                AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off

                Require valid-user
        </Directory>
...
```

Is there a way to allow multiple ldap bases to login to my wiki?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a solution to my problem for now.

By adding the following to my site config in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ i'm able to login with accounts from both DN's. It should be outside the virtualhost.

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap-grid>
        AuthLDAPBindDN cn=admin,dc=grid,dc=aau,dc=dk
        AuthLDAPBindPassword ***
        AuthLDAPURL ldap://localhost:389/ou=People,dc=grid,dc=aau,dc=dk?uid?
        AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative off
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap-es>
        AuthLDAPBindDN cn=admin,dc=es,dc=aau,dc=dk
        AuthLDAPBindPassword ***
        AuthLDAPURL ldap://localhost:389/ou=People,dc=es,dc=aau,dc=dk?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)

</AuthnProviderAlias>
```

The following is the config from the virualhost directory:

```
            AuthBasicProvider ldap-grid ldap-es
            AuthType Basic
            AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
            Require valid-user
```